# delphi узнать length array константы по ссылке на него

Tags: массивы, delphi

узнать length array константы по ссылке на него

```
 const s1=1;
 const s2=2;
 const Messages:Array [0..1] of integer = (s1,s2);

 type
  TA = array of integer;
  var Arr:TA;
  i:integer;
  P:Pointer;
begin
  P:=  @Messages;
  Arr:=TA(P);
  i:=length(TA(P));
```

Я как понял фига я что получу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так не получится, некорректно приводить тип статический массив к динамическому. У динамических массивов (`array of integer`) текущая длина хранится в самом массиве, точнее перед ним, поэтому в дебагере вы видите вычитание числа 16 (10h) из адреса. А у статического массива его длина известна компилятору, но в рантайме не доступна, её нужно отдельно сохранить в какую-нибудь переменную.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов length, примененная к такому массиву в рантайме, вернёт его длину, не обязательно сохранять

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, только что проверил. `length` от статического массива вычисляется при компиляции, а не в рантайме. `i := length(Messages)` в дебаггере выглядит как `i := 2`

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Я с этим и не спорю, сам смотрел в дебаггере :) , я лишь откомментировал, что спец. переменную заводить не надо